# Ionic angular js

Tags: angularjs, getelementbyid, ionic-framework

Hello guys im struggeling with ionic and angular i build an news site view with menu points like this
[ionic menu points](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/bnjrG)
i wrote my news in an array

for example

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWOHlCmZDxUkd4laWN4t?p=catalogue

```
  .controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope) {

        var items = [
            {id: 1, news_item: 'NEWS EXAMPLE'}
        ];

 });
```

how can i route the right path to the news_item.html site which i klicked on. so if i click on first one i get the tempalte with 'NEWS EXAMPLE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't test my answer because your plunker is not working. I think you forgot the index.html file.

But I believe you should add to your items list the url to redirect your page :

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope) {           
  var items = [
    {id: 1, news_item: 'NEWS EXAMPLE', template_url : '/path/to/template'}
  ];
});
```

Then you can add the path to a `href` in your `<a></a>` block.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Change your variable to be `$scope.links` this will make it available in the view for repeating using `ng-repeat`. You can then access values in the JSON Object as setting your `href` value to the `template_url`.

```
    .controller('NewsCtrl',function($scope)({
       $scope.links = [{
              id:1,
              news_item: 'NEWS EXAMPLE',
              template_url: '/path/to/template'
          },
          {
              id:2,
              news_item: 'NEWS EXAMPLE',
              template_url: 'path/to/tempalte'
          }];

    })

<div class='rows' ng-repeat="link in links">
  <a href='{{link.template_url}}' class='col' value='{{link.news_item}}' />
</div>
```

Hope this helps